# writing iced applications outside of main.rs

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and also iced. I am trying to get the counter example from rust working across two files: a lib in a separate directory and the main:

```
root -- crates-- appl -- src -- main.rs
              |
              -- gui -- src -- lib.rs
                            -- gui.rs
```

every rust/iced application I have seen builds the ui in the main.rs. I generally build my applications from the bottom up and then tie everything together. So I wanted to put the ui logic into a separate lib. I can't seem to get the trait containing "run" to import into main.rs.

###### main.rs

```
use iced::{Alignment, Element, Sandbox, Settings};
use iced::widget::{button, column, text};
use gui;

pub fn main() -> iced::Result {
    gui::run(Settings::default())
}
```

###### lib.rs:

```
pub mod gui;
```

###### gui.rs

```
use iced::widget::{button, column, text};
pub use iced::{Alignment, Element, Sandbox, Settings};

struct gui {
    value: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Message {
    IncrementPressed,
    DecrementPressed,
}

impl Sandbox for gui {
    type Message = Message;

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { value: 0 }
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("gui - Iced")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, message: Message) {
        match message {
            Message::IncrementPressed => {
                self.value += 1;
            }
            Message::DecrementPressed => {
                self.value -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fn view(&self) -> Element<Message> {
        column![
            button("Increment").on_press(Message::IncrementPressed),
            text(self.value).size(50),
            button("Decrement").on_press(Message::DecrementPressed)
        ]
        .padding(20)
        .align_items(Alignment::Center)
        .into()
    }
}
```

I am starting to wonder whether you can only set this up with the trait implementation in main.rs?

I tried variations of trying to import the trait, tried using `::` to change the namespace, tried directly importing `run`. Checked I could compile and run when the main function was co located with all the iced stuff.

Answer (score 3):

There are no traits in play here. You're trying to call a function on the *module* `gui`. Modules don't implement traits, and your module never defines a function called `run`, hence your error.

If you intended to call the method on the struct `gui` instead, you need to

```
use gui::gui;

gui::run()
```

Again, as you've pointed out, you'll need to make sure the trait containing `run` is in scope. I don't know the `iced` library you reference, so I can't tell you what trait that is.

Now is also a good time to adopt a consistent naming convention. Rust's naming conventions are pretty standard, and the default compiler settings *should* be warning you in this case. We generally capitalize struct and enum names and keep modules lowercase, so the module should be called `gui` and the struct should be called `Gui`. Naming your declarations in this way will minimize confusion and, perhaps more importantly, make it difficult to confuse a module with a datatype in the future.

Comment: I *think* I started with more or less correct naming but it was one of the things that appeared to be wrong - not matching between all the various places. It was something I am planning to fix once it runs.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `struct gui` (which would idiomatically be capitalized: `struct Gui`), inside a `gui` module inside a `gui` crate. So the proper way to access your `run` method from your application would be:

```
   gui::gui::gui::run (…); // or `gui::gui::Gui::run (…);`
//  ^    ^    ^
//  |    |  struct
//  |  module
// crate
```

This can of course be simplified with proper `use` declarations:

```
use gui::gui::gui; // or `use gui::gui::Gui;`
…
gui::run (…); // or `Gui::run (…);`
```

BTW you should have gotten a compiler warning telling you that `use gui;` in `main.rs` doesn't serve any purpose. That's because it's trying to import the `gui` *crate*, but crates are always in scope so the `use` is redundant.

Note also that having a `gui` crate may be excessive if you don't intend to reuse it for another project. If the goal is just to split the GUI part in another file, it would be simpler to put `gui.rs` in `appl` and declare it with `mod gui;` instead of `use gui;` in `main.rs`. Then you can run it with `gui::Gui::run (…);`